# Update View Controller After connectionDidFinishLoading is Called

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am trying to load web content asynchronously. I am not sure how to update labels/other content in my view controller once the connectionDidFinishLoading method is called. In the sample below, I am just trying to update a label to show that the content has loaded. How would I do this? Thank you!

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[responseData
                                                   length]);
    NSString *txt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: 
    NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    label.text = @"DISPLAY THIS WHEN FINISHED";  
}
```

I have been told to let my viewController be the NSURLConnectionDelegate and then to will run the fetchData method from the viewDidLoad and then use the data you get the data for us when it is fetched in the connectionDidFinishLoading. Anyone know where to begin? Thanks!

Comment: Every view needs to be updated in the main thread.

Comment: I guess my question then is how to update this view on the main thread. Why was this marked down?

Comment: Your question is not very precise, you're just asking how to do it without a real attempt.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Tried to make my question more specific by including details about what I know so far.

Answer (score 1):

As Ramy correctly pointed you must update your UI on the main thread, then :

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
   NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[responseData length]);
   NSString *txt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData 
                                         encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

  NSString *text = @"DISPLAY THIS WHEN FINISHED";
  [label performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:text waitUntilDone:NO]
}
```

Comment: `connectionDidFinishLoading` is called on the same thread on which the connection was started, which is in most cases the main thread (otherwise you have to manage a separate runloop etc. ...). Therefore `performSelectorOnMainThread` is probably not necessary.

Comment: "most cases" and "probably" in your comment, based on what you say there is no guarantee that the method will be called on the main thread, high probability? maybe but not certainty

Comment: OK, I expressed myself badly. What I wanted to say is: Using `performSelectorOnMainThread` in `connectionDidFinishLoading` is only necessary if the connection was not started on the main thread.