# post method in nsurlconnection in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurlconnection

I am new to iOS i need to show particular object for key in textview or picker view using post method response.

coding:

```
NSString *parameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@",user];
            NSData *parameterData = [parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

            url = [NSURL URLWithString: URL];
           NSLog(@"%@", parameterData);
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPBody:parameterData];

            NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[parameterData bytes]];

                  }

        [request setHTTPMethod:method];
        [request addValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
       NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

   if( connection )
        {
            mutableData = [NSMutableData new];

        }
    }
```

delegate method:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *responseStringWithEncoded = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: mutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       // NSLog(@"Response from Server : %@", responseStringWithEncoded);

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: mutableData
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error]; //Now we got top level dictionary
    // (2)

   arrdata =[json objectForKey:@"Branches"];
    //(2)
    NSLog(@"%@",[arrdata valueForKey:@"id"]);



    NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[responseStringWithEncoded dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    serverResponse.attributedText = attrStr;
    //serverResponse.text = arrdata;
}
```

I am successfully showed in NSLOG as below :

[image: screen shot "id" displayed in nslog but not in textview]

**But in `textview` it is not updating.** How can I fix this?

Comment: which data you want to show on textview show that data means show the screen shot of nslog

Comment: Are you sure that serverResonse is linked to your component ?

Comment: First hard-code a text to the serverResponse and see whether it works.

Comment: how to hard-code ??? because i am new this topics please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
serverResponse.text = [arrdata valueForKey:@"id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

> All the UI changes must be carried out in Main thread.

Hence probably this may be the issue.

so, at the end of `connectionDidFinishLoading` wrap `textview` with GCD main queue like below :

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {

         //Update text view
        serverResponse.attributedText = attrStr;
  });
```

Comment: @A.sonu If still not working then, refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039374/update-view-controller-after-connectiondidfinishloading-is-called

Comment: This should not be necessary as the delegate method gets fired on the main thread itself.

Comment: Hi @byJeevan,
I'm not actually clear on what you said.
Are you saying that the delegate gets called in a different thread than the UI thread (main thread)?

Comment: No how to fix asynchronous call @byJeevan

Comment: Glad it works... If my answer helped. Please do accept or upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
         //Update your UI Component here

        serverResponse.attributedText = attrStr;

        //or uncomment below line and comment upper line
        //serverResponse.text = [arrdata valueForKey:@"id"];
  });
```